# Excel, Import Wizard, detecting wrong file type

Tags: microsoft-excel, text-formatting

Each month, I have the privilege to compile daily pipe-delimited files into a monthly Excel workbook.  I use the import wizard to convert the text files into a worksheets in the workbook.  I open all 30 files at once and go through the wizard’s prompts for each file.  The wizard is usually correct in detecting the files are pipe-delimited.  But once, and only once, out of every batch of files, it changes the file type from “Delimited” to “Fixed Width”.   Each file is the same format, Date|Dept|Account|Type|Amount, etc….  Each field contains similar data in all the files. All dates are 8 characters; All Depts are 5 characters; all Accounts are 6 characters; etc….

Why does Excel suddenly not recognize the delimited format of the file?
Why only 1 file of the bunch?

Is it making sure I’m paying attention?

This happens in both Excel 2013 and Excel 365 Pro (MSO 16.0)

Answer (score 0):

If you understand VBA, you could use the following macro, which will ask for a
file name and force importing it as pipe-delimited:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim Filter As String, Title As String
    Dim FilterIndex As Integer
    Dim FileName As Variant

    ' File filters
    Filter = "Text Files (*.dat),*.dat," & "All Files (*.*),*.*"

    ' Default Filter to *.*
    FilterIndex = 3

    ' Set Dialog Caption
    Title = "Select a File to Open"

    ' Select Start Drive & Path
    ChDrive ("G:")
    ChDir ("G:\Scot\MS Excel")

    With Application
        ' Set File Name to selected File
        FileName = .GetOpenFilename(Filter, FilterIndex, Title)
        ' Reset Start Drive/Path
        ChDrive (Left(.DefaultFilePath, 1))
        ChDir (.DefaultFilePath)
    End With

    ' Exit on Cancel
    If FileName = False Then
        MsgBox "No file was selected."
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Import File
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & FileName, Destination:=Range("A1"))
        .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
        .TextFileOtherDelimiter = "|"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

Enter your own values for code below "Select Start Drive & Path".

[source](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/27085333/Import-pipe-delimited-file-into-excel-2007-using-VBA.html)